# MVC - Encrypt dropdown keys and IDs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, url, encryption

I am working on web security. Suppose my request data is the following: I encrypt ID, send in the querystring, but the request data shown has some more keys (pulled from drop down), like sticky and customer key. My question is: do we need to encrypt the drop downs keys as well or just add some validation on the server side? What is the best approach / practice?

```
POST URL?q=%3FDK8wvbvghTwq5hf2jRPryg%253d%253d HTTP/1.1
{  
   "value1":"v1",
   "value2":"v2",
   "sitekey" : "123",
   "customerkey : "45"   
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to encrypt any of these?

Comment: if hacker would change the key with is not related particular company, my dropdown have already filters with proper company. but on post, it do not loading dropdown again for checking the selected key exists or not. do we need to validate this again on post time. or just encrypt the keys

Comment: If this "hacker" has authenticated as someone of another company, that has nothing to do with the values in this POST data.  It sounds like you're not actually enforcing the business rules in the code and are just assuming that the data coming from the user hasn't been tampered with.  That is a *very dangerous* assumption.  You're trying to "secure" your application the entirely wrong way.  You should be authenticating/authorizing users and performing validation logic server-side.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without knowing more about the use-case here. Though I would suggest using HTTPS protocol for the API. Which would encrypt all traffic.

And for authentication there is a lot of solutions. Just to name a few OAuth, Mutual/Two-way authentication, Token based, SASL, Basic auth and so on.

What are your real concerns about your API's security?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the sensitive Ids in your web page, then you have to encrypt them in your code, or use a UUID or a random generated ID column in the database, then display that random value instead of the regular sequential Id. SSL encrypts the data during transition between servers, but the browser decrypts the data, so your Ids in your dropdowns will be exposed if the user views the web page source code.

Also use appropriate permissions to each web page and limit the important data to only what users can see.